# Would rocketry questions be "On-topic"?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Are questions relating to rocketry (Professional, Amateur, and Model) on-topic for this site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Our stance on questions about rocketry should be similar to model aircraft. As discussed regarding [model aircraft](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/324/1696) and [hobby-grade drones](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/1696), it depends on the subject of the question.

- Anything that is very specific to model rockets would be off topic.
- Questions about [airspace regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1313/1696) or physics/aerodynamics would have more relation to aviation in general and [can be on topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17266/1696).
- Questions about avionics or sensors could be on topic if they aren't too specific to rocketry.
- Questions regarding [actually going to space](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/289/1696) would be off topic.

Space questions (and possibly rocket questions) would be better on the [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/) site, and questions without much relevance to aviation could go to [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) depending on the subject.